# SWT: Image inside Composite; Getting IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, swt

I am currently making a stand alone application (not an eclipse plugin) using SWT and Eclipse's WindowBuilder, and I was testing putting an image in a composite to use it as a way to easily plop images into my composites, when I try to draw the image, it throws an IllegalArgumentException. I have no clue what's happening, and I'm looking for an explanation/alternative. What's happening and how would I approach fixing this?

If I comment out the `e.gc.drawImage` line, and nothing more, it will not throw the exception.

Here's the code that's giving me the error:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class GUI {
    public static final Display display = Display.getDefault();;
    private final Shell shell;

    public GUI() {
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI window = new GUI();
        window.open();
    }

    public void open() {
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    private void createContents() {
        shell.setSize(450, 300);

        ImageTest img = new ImageTest(shell, SWT.NONE);
    }
}

import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;

public class ImageTest extends Composite {
    public ImageTest(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        final Image img = new Image(GUI.display, "img.gif");

            // I tried drawing the image to both a canvas and the composite its self. Same outcome.
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(this, SWT.NONE);
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                e.gc.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // If I comment this out, it runs fine.
            }
        });

        img.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because your image is disposed when paintControl tries to draw it. You dispose it yourself at the end of the `ImageTest` constructor before the paint listener gets the chance to even be called.

You can avoid that by making `img` a member variable of your class and then override the dispose methos to do the clean up:

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    this.img.dispose();
    super.dispose();
}
```

Don't forget to remove the line

```
img.dispose();
```

from your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

[GC.drawImage](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/PaintEvent.html) API document says that in the following cases IllegalArgumentException is being thrown. The possibility is that image object is null.

```
IllegalArgumentException -
ERROR_NULL_ARGUMENT - if the image is null
ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT - if the image has been disposed
ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT - if the given coordinates are outside the bounds of the image
```